# How to transfer published resources from CocoStudio to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocostudio

using CocoStudio 2.0.6 and Xcode 6.1.1 on MAC inside VMware. After publishing in CocoStudio I open Xcode and "Add Files to myProject" with the "Copy items if needed" option checked. Then I have the folder myProject/res created by CocoStudio inside the myProject/Resources folder used by Xcode. Using CSLoader in HelloWorldScene.cpp works fine and I see the scene in the simulator. Runs ok also in Eclipse on Android emulator.

If I go back to CocoStudio and make changes like adding a sprite to the scene then I need to repeat the whole process of publishing, delete them Resources/res folder in Xcode and add it again. It is faster to delete the whole folder instead of adding new files into it and delete the ones not used any more.

My question is: am I doing it the right way or is it there a better way for Xcode to automatically see modifications to the resources made by CocoStudio?

Like when I use Eclipse and build the project, the resources in the myProject/proj.android/assets folder are automatically updated with the resources from the myProject/Resources folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a resources folder in iOS app a symbolic link to the main Resources folder.

Remove the proj.ios_mac/Resources folder. Then go to your main app folder and execute:

`ln -s ../Resources proj.ios_mac/Resources`